# Third and second degree polynomial equation solver in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, mathematics

I'm quite new to C++, so as a beginner's project I decided to create a program that can solve second degree polynomials and (some) cubics using this lengthy formula I had found online.

I would love to receive some advice in regards to the code as I am eager to improve my code in any way possible and take away some lessons from more experienced developers.

Here's the code as it is now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class PolynomialSolver {
public:
    static double SolveEquation(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
        array<double, 3> frac_vector1{((pow(-b, 3)) / (27 * pow(a, 3))),
                                    ((b * c) / (6 * pow(a, 2))),
                                    -(d / (2 * a))};
        double frac_vector1_result = 0;
        for (double frac : frac_vector1) {
            frac_vector1_result += frac;
        }

        double frac_vector1_result_pow = pow(frac_vector1_result, 2);

        array<double, 2> frac_vector2 {(c/(3 * a)),
                                     -((pow(b, 2))/(9 * pow(2, a)))};

        double frac_vector2_result = 0;
        for (double frac : frac_vector2) {
            frac_vector2_result += frac;
        }

        double frac_vector2_result_pow3 = pow(frac_vector2_result, 3);

        double first_half = std::cbrt(frac_vector1_result + sqrt(frac_vector1_result_pow + frac_vector2_result_pow3));
        double second_half = std::cbrt(frac_vector1_result - sqrt(frac_vector1_result_pow + frac_vector2_result_pow3));
        double third_half = -(b/3 * a);

        double result = first_half + second_half + third_half;

        if (isnan(result)) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return result;
        }
    }

    static std::pair<double, double> SolveEquation(double a, double b, double c) {
        double positiveRoot = (-b + sqrt(pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c))/(2 * a);
        double negativeRoot = (-b - sqrt(pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c))/(2 * a);

        if (isnan(positiveRoot) || isnan(negativeRoot)) {
            return std::make_pair(0, 0);
        } else {
            return std::make_pair(positiveRoot, negativeRoot);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    double a, b, c, d;
    string option;

    cout << "CHOOSE OPTION: \n\n" << "QUADRATIC (a) \n" << "CUBIC (b) \n" << endl;
    cin >> option;

    string as_lower;
    std::locale loc;
    for (auto elem : option) {
        as_lower += std::tolower(elem, loc);
    }

    if (as_lower == "a") {
        cout << "Input a value for 'a': " << endl;
        cin >> a;

        cout << "Input a value for 'b': " << endl;
        cin >> b;

        cout << "Input a value for 'c': " << endl;
        cin >> c;

        std::pair<double, double> result = PolynomialSolver::SolveEquation(a, b, c);
        cout << "The approximation is " << result.first << ", " << result.second << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Input a value for 'a': " << endl;
        cin >> a;

        cout << "Input a value for 'b': " << endl;
        cin >> b;

        cout << "Input a value for 'c': " << endl;
        cin >> c;

        cout << "Input a value for 'd': " << endl;
        cin >> d;

        double result = PolynomialSolver::SolveEquation(a, b, c, d);
        cout << "The approximation is (may be off by 0.1 to 0.3 decimals) " << result << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would really appreciate some feedback as I understand there may be many problem as it stands currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `pow(2, a)` looks wrong. Did you mean `pow(a, 2)`?
- `frac_vector1_result_pow + frac_vector2_result_pow3` could be negative, yet you blindly `sqrt` it.
- To expand on the above point, cubic equations are tricky. The irreducible case is pretty much unavoidable, and even though the roots are real, you have to deal with complex numbers in the process.

  So my recommendation is to go with `std::complex` from the very beginning.
- Another side note is dealing with degenerate equations. The code allows `a` to be zero, and would obviously crash with a division by zero. However, \$0x^3 + bx^2 + cx +d = 0\$ is a perfectly valid quadratic, and there are roots. No reason to crash at all. Ditto for \$0x^2 + bx + c = 0\$.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Pepijn covered, I'd suggest not using `double` everywhere.  Rather, use a type alias for the type to be used.  At the very least, this will let you update the whole thing when you decide you have to use extended precision values of some kind.  To be more advanced, you can make it a template.

But why is it a class?  You have a *function*.  Or rather, two functions with the same name and different number of arguments.  Making it a static member of a class doesn't do anything useful.

---

A more realistic program would not prompt you for the values like that, but would simply take them on the command line.  Imagine a *real* useful utility where you could simply say

```
Bashprompt> solveit 27.34 -18, 46.334
```

---

`double result = PolynomialSolver::SolveEquation(a, b, c, d);`
Shouldn't it produce up to three results?
For a quadradic, you give two results.  You can call the cubic for with a==0 and expect the same result, so where's the other value?  Clearly this is inconsistent.

You are returning 0 for `isnan`, but zero is *not* a solution!  This is not a good way to distinguish valid from invalid results.  Since you return real roots only you need a way to show that only a subset of the return values are populated.

Calling the two result of the quadratic the positive and negative roots is not good when you have a constant term involved.  Both could be positive, or both could be negative.

---

Finally, [⧺SL.io.50](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#slio50-avoid-endl) Don't use `endl`.

Comment: Actually there is a good way to distinguish valid and invalid results: just let NaNs propagate. Of course, returning a `std::vector` with all roots is probably going to be easier for the caller. You also have to decide how to handle degenerate roots.

Answer (score 2):

My feedback, note I did a code review that means I did not check the correctness of your calculations. You would need to place your calculation methods in a separate library (and then link to executable) and write unit tests for that.

Here are my comments.

```
#include <cmath>        // added (c++ of math library, don't use math.h)
#include <iostream>
// #include <valarray>  include <array>
#include <array>        // for std::array
#include <iomanip>

// using namespace std; <== try not to use this.
// rationale : in larger problems this may lead to name clashes with other libraries
// typing std:: isn't that much work.

class PolynomialSolver final // <== this class is not designed to be inherited from
{
public:

    // todo : refer to documentation of method used to solve 
    // for example I couldn't find the algorithm, and I wanted to check if maybe a matrix based solution was available
    static double SolveEquation(const double a, const double b, const double c, const double d) // <==  parameters you're not going to change in your body should be const
    {   // { <== my style, IMO this makes scopes more clear (and they are important in c++).
        // note : style is a preference. And "holy" wars have been fought about it ;) So usually not covered in reviews

        std::array<const double, 3> frac_vector1 // <== made double a const it will be readonly 
        { // layout fix for readability
            ((std::pow(-b, 3.0)) / (27.0 * std::pow(a, 3.0))),  // 3 ==> 3.0, explicitly initilize as double constant so you don't accidentaly mix ints/doubles
            ((b * c) / (6.0 / std::pow(a, 2.0))),
            -(d / (2.0 * a))
        };

        double frac_vector1_result{ 0.0 }; // you could use aggregate initialization it is now prefered https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

        for (double frac : frac_vector1)
        {
            frac_vector1_result += frac;
        }

        double frac_vector1_result_pow = std::pow(frac_vector1_result, 2);

        std::array<const double, 2> frac_vector2
        {
            (c / (3.0 * a)),
            -((pow(b, 2.0)) / (9.0 * pow(2.0, a)))
        };

        double frac_vector2_result = 0;
        for (double frac : frac_vector2)
        {
            frac_vector2_result += frac;
        }

        double frac_vector2_result_pow3 = pow(frac_vector2_result, 3);

        double first_half = std::cbrt(frac_vector1_result + std::sqrt(frac_vector1_result_pow + frac_vector2_result_pow3));
        double second_half = std::cbrt(frac_vector1_result - std::sqrt(frac_vector1_result_pow + frac_vector2_result_pow3));
        double third_half = -(b / 3 * a);

        double result = first_half + second_half + third_half;

        if (std::isnan(result))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }

    // be explicit, instead of pair create a more readable struct
    // this is also a good place to put the nan check
    struct solution_t
    {
        solution_t(const double pos, const double neg) :
            positiveRoot{ std::isnan(pos) ? 0.0 : pos },
            negativeRoot{ std::isnan(neg) ? 0.0 : neg }
        {
        }

        double positiveRoot{ 0.0 };
        double negativeRoot{ 0.0 };
    };

    // using std::pair is usually not good for readability/maintainability
    static solution_t SolveEquation(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        solution_t solution
        {
            (-b + sqrt(pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a),
            (-b - sqrt(pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)
        };

        return solution;
    }
};

// Input code repeat in main, can be changed to a function
// also improves readability
double get_input_for(char symbol)
{
    double value;
    std::cout << "Input a value for '" << symbol << "': " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> value;
    return value;
}


int main()
{
    // give variables smallest scope possible, this leverages C++ RAII principles.  (unless you need performance optimization)
    //double a, b, c, d; 

    // std::string option; // you only need one input letter
    char option;
    std::cout << "CHOOSE OPTION: \n\n" << "QUADRATIC (a) \n" << "CUBIC (b) \n" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> option;

    /* no longer needed to convert whole string
    std::locale loc;
    for (auto elem : option) {
        as_lower += std::tolower(elem, loc);
    }
    */

    auto choice = std::tolower(option);

    if (choice == 'a')
    {
        auto a = get_input_for('a');
        auto b = get_input_for('b');
        auto c = get_input_for('c');

        auto result = PolynomialSolver::SolveEquation(a, b, c); // keyword auto allows you to easily refactor function return values
        std::cout << "The approximation is " << result.negativeRoot << ", " << result.positiveRoot << std::endl; // negativeRoot, more readable then pair's first
    }
    else
    {
        auto a = get_input_for('a');
        auto b = get_input_for('b');
        auto c = get_input_for('c');
        auto d = get_input_for('d');

        double result = PolynomialSolver::SolveEquation(a, b, c, d);
        std::cout << "The approximation is (may be off by 0.1 to 0.3 decimals) " << result << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow... Beautiful code, thank you. I will take a lot from you've mentioned.

Comment: Happy to help. Don't hesitate to ask questions if you have them

Comment: Oh I forgot, learn to write small functions (like get_input_for). They will help your code explain itself. Usually if you think about start adding comments to explain a piece of code it's worth making a function out of it. (Good code tells a story)

Comment: You're not using `const` enough.